# Licensing text at the bottom of the page links to Stack Overflow regardless on which site you are on

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, help-center, footer

At the bottom of every page, on the right side of the footer there is the text that goes like this:

> Site design / logo © 2022 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions 
> licensed under CC BY-SA. rev 2022.12.6.43080

The "CC BY-SA" links to https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing page on every site on the network.

Even if the help articles is the same, it should link to just the local version of the help centre for the sites. For example https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing

Comment: Pretty sure it's on purpose. Since Stack Overflow is the "main" site, anything related to license, privacy, etc, should be only there.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard then why have the same article on all site's help centres? If what you're saying is true, then most help pages can be consolidated on SO, no need to repeat the information on each stack. Do feel free to post a FR to remove useless help centres. In the mean time, I consider this a bug as I don't it's expected to visit X.SE and then by clicking on a link that's supposed to be about it *and* exists within its domain, you nevertheless end up at Y.SE.

Comment: I'm with you on this, I'm not a fan of this decision, just think it's on purpose. As for the help center, it's all automated, there's automatic copy of all content across all sites, they can't exclude certain pages from it. :/